# Authenticating in a web api vs just a normal web app

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have created 2 very simple methods:

```
[Authorize]
[HttpGet]
public string getUser()
{
   return User.Identity.Name;
}

[HttpPost]
public bool SignIn(Credentials cred)
{
   var user = userRepository.ValidateUser(cred);
   if (user != null)
   {
      if (user.IsActive)
      {
         FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userRepository.GetUserIdByEmail(cred.Email).ToString(), cred.RememberMe);
         FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1,
         user.UserId.ToString(),
         DateTime.UtcNow,
                  DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CookieTimeoutInDays"])),
         true,
         "MyTicket",
         FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);

         //Encrypt the ticket.
         string encTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);

         //Create the cookie.
         HttpCookie mycookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encTicket);

         // Set the cookie's expiration time to the tickets expiration time
         if (ticket.IsPersistent)
            mycookie.Expires = ticket.Expiration;

         Response.AddHeader(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encTicket);
         return true;
       }
       else
       return false;
     }
     else
     {
        return false;
     }
  }
```

I put these functions in an API controller and a normal controller (the only line thats different is `HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encTicket);` when its in the api controller).  When I authenticate with the normal controller and pass the same cookie back to call `getUser()` it works, but when I do it to the API controller it does not work..I am using mobile devices to call both of these controllers, not a browser.  Now I understand API controller usually uses basic authentication by passing in username and password in the headers in each call, but is there anything wrong with doing it from a normal controller?  What are the advantages of using the asp.net web API over just a normal controller?

Comment: I do not recommend using cookies for client authentication in a RESTful API because it means every client has to make an authentication request first (in order to get the cookie to send with subsequent requests), instead I advocate using HTTP Basic or Digest authentication on every request, making the client stateless. The downside is you'll need an SSL certificate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> > When I authenticate with the normal controller and pass the same cookie back to call getUser() it works, but when I do it to the API controller it does not work

I'm not sure why that's the case. If you're using the normal templates, note that your ApiController will live under an /api route, and note that the action name won't be part of the URL. If your WebApiConfig says:

```
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

and your controller class is named FooController, then your ApiController URLs will be something like:
http://:33504/api/Foo

(for both the GET and the POST).

Using cookies with Web API generally isn't the best approach, but it is possible if you have a particular need for it.

There are a couple of other places you might be getting tripped up:

1. You're generating a forms auth cookie twice. The SetAuthCookie line is doing it once, and putting it in a cookie header. Then, the Response.AddHeader is doing it again, putting it in a custom header (not a cookie header).
2. When you say Response.AddHeader(FormsCookieName) I think you meant: Response.SetCookie(myCookie). Your current code is adding a custom header named FormsCookieName; it's not adding a cookie (in the Set-Cookie header) with that cookie name.
3. With Web API, using HttpContext.Current.Response isn't generally recommended. Instead, consider returning HttpResponseMessage and setting the header properties on that object.

> > Now I understand API controller usually uses basic authentication by passing in username and password in the headers in each call, but is there anything wrong with doing it from a normal controller?

When you use Web API, you're generally doing REST and cookies don't fit very well with the hypermedia ideas there. If you're not doing hypermedia/REST, then I suppose you could use cookies, though again it generally isn't the best fit.

> > What are the advantages of using the asp.net web API over just a normal controller?

Web API gives you a self-host story and the ability to do content negotiation and a nice HTTP programming model. MVC was more designed around HTML specifically (not other content types). If you're returning HTML, MVC probably makes sense. If nothing in your app returns HTML, Web API is probably a better fit.

For this one controller, though, I'd do whatever you do in the rest of your app. (I wouldn't pick a different framework for just this one controller.)